# Internal Server Error: the server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration!

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, gcadmin@pair.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

This has something to do with any htcaccess file or something?

This page works perfectly in my localhost, but when I upload it here: http://globalcolleague.com/test/ it throws the error.

Comment: This would be happier on serverfault.com.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think about that.

Comment: Please move to serverfault, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common issue for 500 internal server error on servers with CPanel installed is that you are trying to CHMOD files to 777 permissions when the max the server will safely allow for is 755. Easy fix is to make sure no .php files have 777 permissions, as the server's security will kick in with the 500 error if this is the case.

Comment: -1 There is no such thing as "CPanel servers", Apache is the server... CPanel happens to be the software that somewhat controls Apache. Also, an "internal server error" may show up on all sorts of occasions, from Apache misconfiguration, broken htaccess files, wrong permissions as well as from PHP itself (broken PHP code or even forced through PHP code).

Comment: Wrong spelling of the same thing.

Comment: You get the point, next.

Comment: Got the same issue and solved using this :)